# Interchanging vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, independence

Is it allowed to **interchange** a vector in a basis for another vector that is **linearly independent** to the one you remove?

Comment: $(i,j)$ is a basis for $\Bbb R^2$. $i$ and $j$ are linearly independent. However, you cannot change $i$ for $j$.

Comment: If you meant interchanging vector within a basis, please note that the vectors in a basis does not have any order, so interchanging means nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by allowed? What property do you want to keep intact?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you can interchange it with a vector linearly dependent with the one you remove. (This should have been just a comment but I couldn't write a comment.)

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with the basis $e_{1} = (1,0)$ and $e_{2} = (0,1)$. We are not allowed to remove $e_{1}$ and replace it with $e_{2}$. In that case, we would end up with $(e_{2},e_{2})$, which is not a basis.

What you would be allowed to do is remove $e_{1}$ and replace it with any vector that is linearly independent from $e_{2}$. For example $(1,1)$.
This generalizes to higher dimensions as follows. Suppose we have a basis $e_{1},...,e_{n}$ and we remove the basis vector $e_{j}$. Then we must replace it with another vector, say $v$, that is linearly independent from all the vectors $e_{1},...,e_{n}$ (where $e_{j}$ is not included).

Comment: So it would be allowed to remove a vector from a basis as long as you replace it with a vector that is linear independent from the other vectors in the basis?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea.

Comment: Exactly. The point is that the result is a set of linearly independent vectors.